# How to check whether the cell is empty before saving into data base

Tags: datagridview

hi i have agrid view with 3 columnes i want to check if column 2 & 3 are empty display message saying that before executing save code but i can not do that here is my code to save

```
        //second part
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            condatabase.Open();

            string Query1 = "insert into mal_makbodatsandok_det (ERADID,ERADTYPENAME,BAYAN,MONY) values('"+txtID.Text+"','" + this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "') ;";


            SqlCommand cmddatabase = new SqlCommand(Query1, condatabase);
            myreader = cmddatabase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myreader.Read())
            {

            }

            condatabase.Close();
    }

        MessageBox.Show("saved");
```

plz someone tell me how to check before saving

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == DBNull.Value)
{
    MessageBox.Show("null");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("not null");
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Call method before insertion

```
  if(ValidateGridView() != -99)
  {
    //Insert Logic
  }
  else
  {
    //display error message
  }



    private int ValidateGridView()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
             if(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != string.Empty && 
         this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != string.Empty && 
         this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != string.Empty)
             {}
             else
             {
             return i; 
                 //Return line number and display message, fields on this row number can not be empty
             }
         return -99; //if return is -99 means no row has empty value

         }
   }
```